# What is the relationship between DOM nodes and the javascript namespace?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, jsdom, react-testing-library

In this example, why does the variable `foo` not raise a `ReferenceError`? There is no variable declaration, but it's clearly in scope after the DOM is rendered. What's the relationship between the DOM node id and the javascript namespace? I'm running this with `jest`.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'

test('renders a div', () => {
  const { utils } = render(<div id="foo"/>)
  expect(foo).toBe(true)
})
```

Jest reports:

```
Expected: true
Received: <div id="foo" />
```

I really wish the test would crash instead, because in my real example I accidentally passed an undefined variable to `expect()`, which just happened to share the name of a rendered DOM node's id.

Comment: Browsers do that for stupid legacy reasons.

Comment: @Pointy can you provide a source that documents this behavior?

Comment: `document.write('<div id="foo"/>');
console.log(window.foo)`

Comment: Oh very interesting. I should have gone ever further with minimizing this example. Any reference material about this behavior is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3434388/220272

Comment: @RobertStiffler well probably, but I've been living with it for the better part of 20 years. IE used to do that forever, and Firefox didn't, so there were endless bugs because of that. It's similar to the issue of the global `event` reference vs. the parameter passed to event handlers.

Comment: @Pointy Based on the accepted answer, it appears this was originally unstandardized behavior of IE, but has now been "standardized by HTML5, whose approach is to document and standardize every terrible practice inflicted on us by browser authors, making them part of the web forever". :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Elements with ids become global variables**

*Not the same question, but the answer to your question is another SO question:*

— [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables)